# Update Flag Based On Change of Previous Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table .Need sql ,If there is change in INPUT value then update FLAG to 1 else 0.

```
INPUT   START_DATE  PERSON_ID  FLAG
42707   2017-01-01  227317      0
40000   2018-01-01  227317      1
42400   2019-01-01  227317      1
42400   2019-01-02  227317      0
```

Comment: In your data, `input` is unique for the person, so you are only flagging whether or not the row is the first row.

Comment: Now u check can check from 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-02  there is no change in INPUT,so its flag should be 0

Answer (score 1):

If you want this in a query, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by person_id order by start_date) = 1
             then 0 else 1
        end) as flag
from t;
```

If the `input_value` could be the same on different rows, then use `first_value()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when value <> first_value(input) over (partition by person_id order by start_date) = 1
             then 0 else 1
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Either form could be incorporated into an `update` using an updatable CTE if you want to update the table.

EDIT:

If you want to know if the value changes from one row to the "next", then use `lag()`.  In an `update`, this looks like:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             lag(input) over (partition by customerid order by date) as prev_input
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set flag = (case when prev_input <> input then 1 else 0 end);
```

That said, I would not advise you to store the data in the table.  Instead, just put the logic in a `select` when you need it.  Otherwise, the data could get out of date if a historical value is updated.

Comment: You can check  from 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-02 there is no change in INPUT,so its flag should be 0

Comment: Any method to do without using lag function?

Comment: @at9063 . . . All supported versions of SQL Server support `lag()`, so I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` :

```
select t.*, 
       (case when lag(input, 1, input) over (partition by person_id order by start_date) = input
             then 0 else 1 
        end) as FLAG
from table t;
```